# iOS 14 : app hangs on uinavigationController push action and hangs the app

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios14

In iOS14 devices, my app does not load the view controllers and just freeze the app.

`self.navigationController!.pushViewController(itemDetailVC, animated: true)`

On all device below iOS 14, it works perfectly fine. But here it does not load the next view controller.

While debugging I figured that `viewDidAppear` never gets called.

Anyone else facing such issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my case there were some weird layout constraint issues that were stopping the view from loading only for ios14. The issues were making the storyboard loading also difficult. Had to eventually fix them one by one on a lower version of Xcode.
But finally it worked

Answer (score 0):

Getting very strange problems with UINavigationController transition animations. Resulting view controllers appear broken and shifted. Unbelievable how broken it is.

The issue is due to mistakes on view controller override functions. Double check your onViewWill/onViewDidAppear. The should override the correct function

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    Logger.verbose(topic: .appState, message: "viewWillAppear")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    Logger.verbose(topic: .appState, message: "viewDidAppear")
}
```

Also, if you are using a UITabBarController, make sure the same thing is done correctly there too.